# The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, field

I get the bellow error in the console, when I run server in my PyCharm:

```
ERRORS:
frontend.Users.ctime: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.
frontend.Users.uptime: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.
```

My models `Users` code is below:

```py
class Users(models.Model):
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.now())
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=datetime.now())
```

Why I get this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It will work.

Explanation:

These both are mutually exclusive means you should use only one of them, not both.

Comment: Do you mean the `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` will set the time automatically？

Comment: Yes, It will set time automatically. That's what they are for. Also, they will set current time automatically. So, you don't need to add `default=datetime.now()`.

Comment: Why were you even using then if you didn't know they set the time? That is literally all they do.

Comment: When we add this for an existing table, what should be the default value?

Comment: I went looking for this when I did some migrations and Django wanted me to put in some defaults or add a default option. So they clash in the class definition but if adding to existing database, you need to provide defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ERRORS: app1.Person.updated_at: (fields.E160) The options auto_now,
> auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these
> options may be present.

Because I set both [auto_now=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [auto_now_add=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, # Here 
        auto_now_add=True # Here
    )
    ...
```

So, I removed one of them as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        # auto_now=True, # Here 
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    ...
```

```py
# "app1/models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        # auto_now_add=True # Here
    )
    ...
```

In addition, the doc says below in [DateField.auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> The options `auto_now_add`, `auto_now`, and `default` are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

When the table already exists I just used django.utils.timezone.now() . The main difference has to do with the database settings. When using the auto_now or auto_now_add options, the model field will have editable=False, as per documentation @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield .

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by giving a default value to `DateField` i.e `models.DateField('01-01-0000')`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).